# Input acepta el espacio en blanco

Tags: javascript

Si le doy click sin ingresar nada se activa el *alert* pero si le doy un espacio en blanco lo pasa como si hubiera agregado una palabra ¿Qué puedo añadirle al script para que valide si se ingreso una letra? si no, vuelva a activar el *alert*

```js
var n = document.getElementById("name");

var b = document.getElementById("button");

b.onclick = function () {

if (n.value == "") {

alert("Vacío");

} else {

document.write("Tu nombre es:" + " " + n.value);

}

}
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
<button id="button">Validar</button>
```

Comment: @BetaM que no es mucho mejor directamente hacer trim de la cadena?

Comment: Claro, por eso lo dejé como comentario por que puede ser eso o trim

Answer (score 3):

Deberías usar [`String.prototype.trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), este método quita espacios innecesarios al inicio y al final

> El método `trim()` elimina los espacios en blanco en ambos extremos del string. Los espacios en blanco en este contexto, son todos los caracteres sin contenido (espacio, tabulación, etc.) y todos los caracteres de nuevas lineas (LF,CR,etc.).

```js
const n = document.getElementById("name");
const b = document.getElementById("button");

b.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (n.value.trim() == "") {
        alert("Vacío");
    } else {
        document.write("Tu nombre es:" + " " + n.value.trim());
    }
});
```

```html
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Nombre">
<button id="button">Validar</button>
```